# Not able to remove cookies with react-cookie

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-cookie

I'm using [react-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie) for setting cookies in the browser. Now I want to remove a cookie. Unfortunately I'm not able to remove the string using the following call:

```
cookies.remove(cookies.cookies.slug,{ path: '/'})
```

If I console.log the remove call I get an undefined back in my browser console.